# Method keyFromPemFileWithName not found on JWTCryptoSecurity class

Tags: ios, swift, docusignapi, java-web-start

Have someone faced any error when trying to integrate DocuSign SDK on Swift iOS application? I have installed the last version of DocuSign (3.0.1) using Cocoapods and it has a dependency of **JWT framework** (version 3.0.0-beta.11 installed).

I try to run the code but I got this error: No known class method for selector **No known class method for selector 'keyFromPemFileWithName:'**

It seems there is no method keyFromPemFileWithName inside JWTCryptoSecurity class.

I would appreciate if someone has the answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found 2 ways to solve this issue
1) Force to use an old version of JWS with DocuSign:

pod 'JWT', :git => 'https://github.com/yourkarma/JWT', :commit => 'c4232478d3190a163f76b05c38ec84625e3d785a'
  pod 'DocuSignESign'

2) Edit DocuSign framework in order to have a method like that (without passing the file name but the file URL)